# Could somebody explain the functions of a member function with the delaration 'explicit operator const GUID_t&() const'?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, overloading, c++17

What's the function of 'operator const GUID_t&() const' in the code snippet below.

It's quoted from a wellknown open source project,so i don't doublt the correctness.It does not look like ordenary operator overload,eg:`CTest operrator(CTest&&)`, which you could clearly know the return type.Is there a term for this kind of usage?I would be grateful to have some help with this question.It would be better that if you could give a few such examples.

```
struct GUID_t{};
struct InstanceHandle_t
{
    explicit operator const GUID_t&() const
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<const GUID_t*>(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [user-defined conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [user-defined conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) of a general form:

```
operator T();
```

Here:

```
T = const GUID_t&
```

That is, it allows instances of `InstanceHandle_t` to be converted to `const GUID_t&` using the operations defined in the operator's body.

The additional `explicit` specifier is optional, and prevents implicit conversion, i.e., the compiler will trigger this conversion only in explicit contexts, such as:

```
InstanceHandle_t handler;

GUID_t guid(handler);
static_cast<GUID_t>(handler);
const GUID_t& ref(handler);
```

All the three statements result in executing:

```
*reinterpret_cast<const GUID_t*>(&handler)
```

Like other operators, invoking it directly is also possible:

```
handler.operator const GUID_t&();
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.One more question, what's the return type of `operator T();`?

Comment: @John It's `T`, that's why you don't need to spell it twice.